# Eigen values of the operator $T : V \rightarrow V : T(f(t)) = t f~'(t)$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be the linear space of all real functions differentiable on $(0,1)$. If $f \in V,$ define $q = T(f(t))$ to mean that $q(t) = tf~'(t) ~\forall ~t \in (0,1)$ Prove that every real $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue for $T$

**Attempt:**

Given that $T(f(t)) = tf~'(t) $

Suppose $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $T$. Then :

$\lambda f(t) =tf~'(t) ~~~~......................(1)$.

Solving this, we get $ \lambda \ln t- \ln f=c$, where $c$ is any arbitrary constant.

Now, the above equation is valid for any value of $ \lambda$. Hence, $ \lambda$ can be any real value.

Is my attempt correct?

Thank you for your help in this regard.

Comment: This looks correct, though it might be worth pointing out that one can actually produce eigenfunctions $f$ of $T$, rather than producing an equation that any eigenfunction must satisfy and asserting that there is always such a function. (Of course, doing so is easy in this case.)

Comment: for every $\lambda \in R, \, t^\lambda$ is an eigenfunction corresponding to the eigenvalue $\lambda.$

Comment: @Travis and @.Abel Thank you for your comments. Got it.

Comment: This problem is incorrectly stated: the linear map does not send $V\to V$, and so one cannot really talk about its eigenvalues. The problem is that just supposing $f$ differentiable does not make $f'$ differentiable. The only way out I know of is restricting to the case of indefinitely often differentiable functions (class $\mathcal C^\infty$).

Comment: @Wanderer You're welcome.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen What are "eigenvalues" called in this case? (The case that we accept that the image may only be $\mathcal C^0$)

Comment: @GPerez: There is no standard terminology when it is not about linear operators (going from a space to itself). Here one has an injective map $\iota:V\to W$ (with for instance $W$ _all_ real valued function on $(0,1)$); this is the embedding of differentiable functions into them), and another map $T:V\to W$ (the one specified in the question). One may ask for which constants $\lambda$ the difference $f-\lambda\iota:V\to W$ fails to be injective. Putting $V_0=V$ and $V_{i+1}=\iota^{-1}[T(V_i)]$ for $i\in\Bbb N$, these $\lambda$ _are_ eigenvalues of an obvious linear operator on $\bigcap_i V_i$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The differential equation you need to solve $tf'(t)= \lambda f(t)$ so $f'(t)-\frac{\lambda}{t}f(t)=0$ (you can divide by t, since it's non zero by asumption). An integrating factor is hence $t^{-\lambda}$. Multiplying both sides bu $t^{-\lambda}$ you get $t^{-\lambda}f'(t)-\lambda t^{-\lambda-1} f(t)=0$, which is $\frac{d}{dt}(f(t) t^{-\lambda})=0$. Hence $f(t)t^{-\lambda}=c$ so $f(t)=ct^{\lambda}$. Hence any real is an eigenvalue.